# Sympy roots function creating huge trigonometric expressions

Tags: python, math, sympy

I was trying to find the roots of this equation in python sympy:
`roots(-64*x**7 + 112*x**5 - 56*x**3 + 7*x)`
and I set a domain for the answer of this result, getting only one answer that

algebrically corresponds to approx. `0.433883739117558`,

is equal to

```
sqrt(7/12 - (7^(2/3) (1 + i sqrt(3)))/(12 2^(2/3) (-1 + 3 i sqrt(3))^(1/3)) - 1/24 (1 - i sqrt(3)) (7/2 (-1 + 3 i sqrt(3)))^(1/3))
```

but sympy throws this expression at me:

```
sqrt(6)*(-56*sqrt(7)*cos(atan(3*sqrt(3))/3)**3 - 56*sqrt(7)*cos(atan(3*sqrt(3))/3)**3*cos(2*atan(3*sqrt(3))/3) - 56*sqrt(7)*sin(atan(3*sqrt(3))/3)*sin(2*atan(3*sqrt(3))/3)*cos(atan(3*sqrt(3))/3)**2 - 56*sqrt(7)*sin(atan(3*sqrt(3))/3)**2*cos(atan(3*sqrt(3))/3) - 56*sqrt(7)*sin(atan(3*sqrt(3))/3)**2*cos(atan(3*sqrt(3))/3)*cos(2*atan(3*sqrt(3))/3) - 56*sqrt(7)*sin(atan(3*sqrt(3))/3)**3*sin(2*atan(3*sqrt(3))/3) + 28*sin(atan(3*sqrt(3))/3)**2*cos(2*atan(3*sqrt(3))/3)**2 + 28*sin(atan(3*sqrt(3))/3)**2*sin(2*atan(3*sqrt(3))/3)**2 + 28*sin(atan(3*sqrt(3))/3)**2 + 56*sin(atan(3*sqrt(3))/3)**2*cos(2*atan(3*sqrt(3))/3) + 196*sin(atan(3*sqrt(3))/3)**4 + 28*cos(atan(3*sqrt(3))/3)**2*cos(2*atan(3*sqrt(3))/3)**2 + 28*sin(2*atan(3*sqrt(3))/3)**2*cos(atan(3*sqrt(3))/3)**2 + 28*cos(atan(3*sqrt(3))/3)**2 + 56*cos(atan(3*sqrt(3))/3)**2*cos(2*atan(3*sqrt(3))/3) + 392*sin(atan(3*sqrt(3))/3)**2*cos(atan(3*sqrt(3))/3)**2 + 196*cos(atan(3*sqrt(3))/3)**4)**(1/4)*cos(atan(-2*sqrt(7)*sin(2*atan(3*sqrt(3))/3)*cos(atan(3*sqrt(3))/3)/(-2*sqrt(7)*cos(atan(3*sqrt(3))/3) - 2*sqrt(7)*cos(atan(3*sqrt(3))/3)*cos(2*atan(3*sqrt(3))/3) - 2*sqrt(7)*sin(atan(3*sqrt(3))/3)*sin(2*atan(3*sqrt(3))/3) + 14*sin(atan(3*sqrt(3))/3)**2 + 14*cos(atan(3*sqrt(3))/3)**2) + 2*sqrt(7)*sin(atan(3*sqrt(3))/3)*cos(2*atan(3*sqrt(3))/3)/(-2*sqrt(7)*cos(atan(3*sqrt(3))/3) - 2*sqrt(7)*cos(atan(3*sqrt(3))/3)*cos(2*atan(3*sqrt(3))/3) - 2*sqrt(7)*sin(atan(3*sqrt(3))/3)*sin(2*atan(3*sqrt(3))/3) + 14*sin(atan(3*sqrt(3))/3)**2 + 14*cos(atan(3*sqrt(3))/3)**2) + 2*sqrt(7)*sin(atan(3*sqrt(3))/3)/(-2*sqrt(7)*cos(atan(3*sqrt(3))/3) - 2*sqrt(7)*cos(atan(3*sqrt(3))/3)*cos(2*atan(3*sqrt(3))/3) - 2*sqrt(7)*sin(atan(3*sqrt(3))/3)*sin(2*atan(3*sqrt(3))/3) + 14*sin(atan(3*sqrt(3))/3)**2 + 14*cos(atan(3*sqrt(3))/3)**2))/2)/12 + sqrt(6)*I*(-56*sqrt(7)*cos(atan(3*sqrt(3))/3)**3 - 56*sqrt(7)*cos(atan(3*sqrt(3))/3)**3*cos(2*atan(3*sqrt(3))/3) - 56*sqrt(7)*sin(atan(3*sqrt(3))/3)*sin(2*atan(3*sqrt(3))/3)*cos(atan(3*sqrt(3))/3)**2 - 56*sqrt(7)*sin(atan(3*sqrt(3))/3)**2*cos(atan(3*sqrt(3))/3) - 56*sqrt(7)*sin(atan(3*sqrt(3))/3)**2*cos(atan(3*sqrt(3))/3)*cos(2*atan(3*sqrt(3))/3) - 56*sqrt(7)*sin(atan(3*sqrt(3))/3)**3*sin(2*atan(3*sqrt(3))/3) + 28*sin(atan(3*sqrt(3))/3)**2*cos(2*atan(3*sqrt(3))/3)**2 + 28*sin(atan(3*sqrt(3))/3)**2*sin(2*atan(3*sqrt(3))/3)**2 + 28*sin(atan(3*sqrt(3))/3)**2 + 56*sin(atan(3*sqrt(3))/3)**2*cos(2*atan(3*sqrt(3))/3) + 196*sin(atan(3*sqrt(3))/3)**4 + 28*cos(atan(3*sqrt(3))/3)**2*cos(2*atan(3*sqrt(3))/3)**2 + 28*sin(2*atan(3*sqrt(3))/3)**2*cos(atan(3*sqrt(3))/3)**2 + 28*cos(atan(3*sqrt(3))/3)**2 + 56*cos(atan(3*sqrt(3))/3)**2*cos(2*atan(3*sqrt(3))/3) + 392*sin(atan(3*sqrt(3))/3)**2*cos(atan(3*sqrt(3))/3)**2 + 196*cos(atan(3*sqrt(3))/3)**4)**(1/4)*sin(atan(-2*sqrt(7)*sin(2*atan(3*sqrt(3))/3)*cos(atan(3*sqrt(3))/3)/(-2*sqrt(7)*cos(atan(3*sqrt(3))/3) - 2*sqrt(7)*cos(atan(3*sqrt(3))/3)*cos(2*atan(3*sqrt(3))/3) - 2*sqrt(7)*sin(atan(3*sqrt(3))/3)*sin(2*atan(3*sqrt(3))/3) + 14*sin(atan(3*sqrt(3))/3)**2 + 14*cos(atan(3*sqrt(3))/3)**2) + 2*sqrt(7)*sin(atan(3*sqrt(3))/3)*cos(2*atan(3*sqrt(3))/3)/(-2*sqrt(7)*cos(atan(3*sqrt(3))/3) - 2*sqrt(7)*cos(atan(3*sqrt(3))/3)*cos(2*atan(3*sqrt(3))/3) - 2*sqrt(7)*sin(atan(3*sqrt(3))/3)*sin(2*atan(3*sqrt(3))/3) + 14*sin(atan(3*sqrt(3))/3)**2 + 14*cos(atan(3*sqrt(3))/3)**2) + 2*sqrt(7)*sin(atan(3*sqrt(3))/3)/(-2*sqrt(7)*cos(atan(3*sqrt(3))/3) - 2*sqrt(7)*cos(atan(3*sqrt(3))/3)*cos(2*atan(3*sqrt(3))/3) - 2*sqrt(7)*sin(atan(3*sqrt(3))/3)*sin(2*atan(3*sqrt(3))/3) + 14*sin(atan(3*sqrt(3))/3)**2 + 14*cos(atan(3*sqrt(3))/3)**2))/2)/12
```

Which is correct, but extremely overcomplicated. I tried using symplify(), and other functions, but I couldn't come up with any way to fix this How do I solve this problem?

I also found it to be pretty common for sympy to solve an expression using trigonometric functions, present aswell with `-1024*x11 + 2816*x9 - 2816*x7 + 1232*x5 - 220*x**3 + 11*x`

Comment: Well, see if you can get sympy to solve the equation x^5-x+1=0. Sometimes "simple" is in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: @lastchance that equation has no radical solutions, but mine does

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Fixed! Stack overflow noobie here hahah

Comment: Also remember to show the actual code you wrote (in [mcve] form) even if it's only two imports and a function call =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn off trig functions with `trig=False` to get only radical expressions. I tend to think that radical (or radical-trig) expressions are not useful if Cardano's formulae are involved though. It is usually better to avoid using `roots` since its purpose is to return such expressions (although it could be improved to return simpler expressions). Instead it is usually better to use factorisation and RootOf to represent roots.

The best way to represent the roots of a polynomial like this is just using RootOf:

```
In [23]: p = -64*x**7 + 112*x**5 - 56*x**3 + 7*x

In [24]: for r in real_roots(p): print(r)
CRootOf(64*x**6 - 112*x**4 + 56*x**2 - 7, 0)
CRootOf(64*x**6 - 112*x**4 + 56*x**2 - 7, 1)
CRootOf(64*x**6 - 112*x**4 + 56*x**2 - 7, 2)
0
CRootOf(64*x**6 - 112*x**4 + 56*x**2 - 7, 3)
CRootOf(64*x**6 - 112*x**4 + 56*x**2 - 7, 4)
CRootOf(64*x**6 - 112*x**4 + 56*x**2 - 7, 5)

In [25]: [r.n(3) for r in real_roots(p)]
Out[25]: [-0.975, -0.782, -0.434, 0, 0.434, 0.782, 0.975]
```

You can wrap that up in a number symbol for nicer display e.g.:

```
In [34]: a = real_roots(p)[4]

In [35]: a.n()
Out[35]: 0.433883739117558

In [36]: alpha = AlgebraicNumber(a, alias="alpha")

In [37]: alpha
Out[37]: α

In [38]: alpha.n()
Out[38]: 0.433883739117558
```

For this particular polynomial `Q(alpha)` is the splitting field so all roots can be found in terms of alpha:

```
In [40]: print(p.factor(extension=alpha))
-64*x*(x - alpha)*(x + alpha)*(x - 3*alpha + 4*alpha**3)*(x - 4*alpha**3 + 3*alpha)*(x - 5*alpha - 16*alpha**5 + 20*alpha**3)*(x - 20*alpha**3 + 16*alpha**5 + 5*alpha)

In [45]: print(p.factor(extension=alpha).n(3))
-64.0*x*(x - 0.975)*(x - 0.782)*(x - 0.434)*(x + 0.434)*(x + 0.782)*(x + 0.975)

In [50]: print(ground_roots(p, domain=QQ.algebraic_field(alpha)))
{0: 1, -20*alpha**3 + 16*alpha**5 + 5*alpha: 1, -3*alpha + 4*alpha**3: 1, alpha: 1, -alpha: 1, -4*alpha**3 + 3*alpha: 1, -5*alpha - 16*alpha**5 + 20*alpha**3: 1}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The Trig = False answers my question, but the other option is very interesting aswell, but not suited for my purpose of getting an exact radical solution. Thanks!

Comment: I've been trying to figure this out, but I think the trig = Fase is not working? I used this code: ```from sympy import *
import sympy
from sympy.abc import k, m, n, x

print(roots(-64*x**7 + 112*x**5 - 56*x**3 + 7*x, trig = False))``` and it still outputs a trig function: -sqrt(6)*(-56*sqrt(7)*cos(atan(3*sqrt(3))/3)**3 - 56*sqrt(7)*cos(atan(3*sqrt(3))/3)**3*cos(2*atan(3*sqrt(3))/3) - 56*sqrt(7)*sin... (small snippet) How could I fix this? I am trying to create a formula for sin(pi/n) so having approximations or trig functions in the solutions is simply counterproductive

Comment: The trig functions are coming from expand(complex=True) being called somewhere. I think it would be better to open a GitHub issue.

Comment: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/26130

Comment: Yup! That is me

Answer (score 0):

Your original equation has a trivial solution of x=0 which the algebra system has factored out first.

```
-64*x**7 + 112*x**5 - 56*x**3 + 7*x
(-64x^6 + 112x^4 - 56x^2 + 7)x
```

It has then solved the equation inside the brackets as a cubic equation in x^2 using trig identities which does work but isn't especially pretty. TBH I think it has done well to obtain a real number solution as opposed to a messy complex expression for a real number - but I suppose beauty is in the eye of the beholder.

Its choice of algebraic representation does leave something to be desired though. It seems to be unaware of the obscure identity that would allow simplification here - namely:

```
6cos(2pi/7) = 2sqrt(7)cos(atan(3sqrt(3))-1
```

See for example [construction of a heptagon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heptagon#Construction) for details.

A mark one eyeball suggests that your coefficients are identical to those of the the Chebyshev polynomial T<sub>7</sub>(x) = cos(7 acos(x)) (give or take a sign convention) whose roots are all real and on the range -1 to 1.

Plotting it confirms this:
[image]

Therefore the most elegant expression of the real roots of this equation would be:

```
 0 = cos(7 acos(x))
 (2n+1)pi/2 = 7 acos(x)
 so
 x = cos( (2n+1)pi/14 )
```

In analytical closed form your chosen root being

```
 cos( 5pi/14 ) = 0.433883739117558
```

I wonder if any of the generative AI tools are yet capable of making that connection without being given a strong hint by a human? I confess that I have spent too much time staring at these polynomials.

Your second example is -T<sub>11</sub>(x) so again it isn't at all surprising that it will choose a trigonometric representation to solve it. I'm impressed that it will actually do that for a special case high order equation.

FWIW Maxima 20.12.1 gets the series of answers as your first example. And it is unable to simplify to a real number by itself (at least with me driving it). I wonder if Mathematica can do any better with this one?

Comment: One of the solutions of this equations is equivalent to sin(pi/7), which is what I am looking for. This is the reason why trig identities, while pretty, are kinda useless for my project

Comment: If you want the algebra system to give you an answer in that form why not cast the problem as 0 = T<sub>N</sub> = cos(N*acos(x)) and ask it to solve for x. Maxima only gives me the principle solution as cos(pi/14) then and warns that some solutions have been lost. I'm a bit disappointed that none of them make a decent fist of turning their derived complex expressions (as in with imaginary components that cancel out) for the polynomial roots into a nice pure real root (which it is).

Comment: When I do that, unfortunately it does not output the radical expression, only the sine and cosine values

Comment: What are you trying to do? It might be easier to accomplish  in a scratchpad algebra system...

Comment: I am trying to get exact radical values for sin and cos of pi/n, where n is specified by the user. to do this, I used the general equation for the sin(npi), and substituted to get 0 = (expression), like the one above, which was the output for n = 7. This creates extra solutions, which I filter out with an if statement (sin n/pi = approx(root)) and then print out the result. Maybe overcomplicated, but it's not meant to be a serious procedure, and tbh I am kinda proud I managed to kinda do it in a new language for me in 2 days